# How can I make a service running in Guest VM in VirtualBox accessible outside the VM

Tags: virtualbox, opensuse, port-forwarding, nat

I use Oracle VirtualBox and have a service that runs on a guest VM. If I'm under guest OS and open the service URL in Firefox the app works as expected:

```
https://localhost:8443
```

I was told that I can use NAT and port forwarding feature to make the service available outside the guest VM but it didn't give me the desired result. I did the following:

Guest VM (OpenSUSE Leap 15.0):

I activated http and https

```
Yast -> Software -> Firewall
```

[image]

VirtualBox:

```
VM Settings -> Network -> Adapter 1
Attached to: NAT
Port Forwarding
```

[image]

Restarted the VM and opened
`https://localhost:4444` in a web browser on the host OS
but got `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` instead of the web app login window.

Output of `netstat` on the host

```
$ netstat -a
...
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2222           WD-DT-11AD:0           LISTENING
...
  TCP    0.0.0.0:4444           WD-DT-11AD:0           LISTENING
...
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8888           WD-DT-11AD:0           LISTENING
...
```

I also corrected the guest ports as suggested in comments to 8443 and to 8080 correspondingly, but it didn't help.

What is missed in my configuration? Is there anything else I have to set up (maybe in the guest VM)?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to port 443 or to port 8443 on the guest? It looks like you listed both ports. Was that a typo?

Comment: @igal no. The service is accessible under the link localhost:8443 when I open it in a browser in guest OS. But the official port number is 443 (at least if I view the port number of https service in Yast). That's why I use it in port forwarding. Do you think it makes some difference? No, I've just changed it to 8443 in port forwarding dialog.

Comment: It definitely makes a difference which port the application is running on. You don't need to forward to the "official" port, you need to forward to the port that is actually being used. If the service is accessible on port 8443, then that should be the target of your port-forwarding rule.

Comment: @igal, thanks. You gave me the right direction. After I added the both ports to the list of accessible ports the service became accessible from the host OS.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple. I just had to add the port 8443 to the list of accessible ports in Yast Firewall. It's the tab "Ports" on the screenshot. The web app became accessible from the host OS after that.